# Locrian mode is not part of standard usage?

Tags: scales, modes, history

I got this answer on one of my questions:

> The Locrian mode is mostly a music theory concept in western music
>   history, and it is very rarely used for music pieces that use western
>   harmony, but as a mode for monophonic music it is fine.

Does that mean Locrian mode is not part of standard usage?

Comment: What is "standard usage," and what difference does that make? You won't find a lot of tunes in the Locrian mode, but they do exist. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Probably used in less than 1% of 'standard' tunes. Thus not much used in 'standard usage'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some things in music where there are standards and standard usages. Much of standard notation is, well, standard; things like the MIDI protocol and file formats are standardised; a concert pitch of A4=440 is an agreed-on standard (albeit not the only one).

However, when it comes to what notes and tonalities to *choose*, There is (thankfully!) no agreed-upon "standard usage" in music. The original phrasing - that Locrian is *rarely used* - is more precise.

The other sense in which 'standard' could be used is to indicate that a concept is commonly *understood* - whether the word has a 'standard' meaning. In this sense, modern 'Locrian' probably *is* standard, because what the word 'Locrian' *means* is recognised and understood alongside the other mode names.